# php file_put_content overwrite

Tags: php, mysql

So i found this code which lets be write to a specific line

```
  function SetSiteName(){
        global $session, $database, $form;
    $filepathname = "include/classes/constants.php";
    $target = 'sitename';
    $newline = 'define("sitename", "Testing.");';

    $stats = file($filepathname, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);   
    $offset = array_search($target,$stats) +32;
    array_splice($stats, $offset, 0, $newline);   
    file_put_contents($filepathname, join("\n", $stats)); 
    header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
   }
```

however it will not overwrite whats on that line it'll go to the next line and put the data in.. I'd like to make it overwrite what currently is on that line?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite a line of a file with this code.

```
$filename = "file.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$lines_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);

//overwrite the line that you want.
$lines_array[5] = "New text at line 6!";

file_put_contents($filename, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines_array));
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me? It just adds a new line after it.